# How tuples or rows do usually called in statistics?

Tags: statistics, terminology

Is there a special term for couple of measured values of single event in statistics? This is called `record`, `tuple` or `table row` in other sciences.

Answer (score 1):

It's often called an **observation**. That's also the langauge used in e.g. SAS.